# Avoid backreference replacement in php's preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

Consider the below use of `preg_replace`

```
$str='{{description}}';
$repValue='$0.0 $00.00 $000.000 $1.1 $11.11 $111.111';

$field = 'description';
$pattern = '/{{'.$field.'}}/';

$str =preg_replace($pattern, $repValue, $str );
echo $str;


// Expected output: $0.0 $00.00 $000.000 $1.1 $11.11 $111.11
// Actual output:   {{description}}.0 {{description}}.00 {{description}}0.000 .1 .11 1.111
```

#### Here is a [phpFiddle showing the issue](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/dhxu-9k4r)

It's clear to me that the actual output is not as expected because `preg_replace` is viewing `$0, $0, $0, $1, $11, and $11` as back references for matched groups replacing `$0` with the full match and `$1 and $11` with an empty string since there are no capture groups 1 or 11.

How can I prevent `preg_replace` from treating prices in my replacement value as back references and attempting to fill them?

Note that `$repValue` is dynamic and it's content will not be know before the operation.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `preg_replace`, not `str_replace`?

Comment: @Barmar , you're right, I could actually just use `str_replace`, thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape the dollar character before using a character translation (`strtr`):

```
$repValue = strtr('$0.0 $00.00 $000.000 $1.1 $11.11 $111.111', ['$'=>'\$']);
```

For more complicated cases (with dollars and escaped dollars) you can do this kind of substitution *(totally waterproof this time)*:

```
$str = strtr($str, ['%'=>'%%', '$'=>'$%', '\\'=>'\\%']);
$repValue = strtr($repValue, ['%'=>'%%', '$'=>'$%', '\\'=>'\\%']);
$pattern = '/{{' . strtr($field, ['%'=>'%%', '$'=>'$%', '\\'=>'\\%']) . '}}/';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, $repValue, $str );
echo strtr($str, ['%%'=>'%', '$%'=>'$', '\\%'=>'\\']);
```

Note: if `$field` contains only a literal string (not a subpattern), you don't need to use `preg_replace`. You can use `str_replace` instead and in this case you don't have to substitute anything.

Comment: No. Just specific preg_quote()

Comment: @Deep: no, `preg_quote` is only designed for patterns and is not appropriate for replacement strings (make the test)

Comment: Ou... for replacement. Sorry.